# Deploying C# 7 code to VSTS

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, c#-7.0

I have a project where I am using C# 7 features. It builds fine locally, but when I build in Visual Studio Team Services, I get errors. All the errors point to this one project and they all look related to C# 7:

```
 Identifier expected
 Invalid expression term 'int'
 Syntax error, ',' expected
 Syntax error, '>' expected
 ) expected
 ; expected
```

The project targets.NET 4.6.1 and references Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform 1.0.3 and Micosoft.Net.Compilers 2.0.1.

How can I get the project to build on VSTS?

Comment: Keep in mind where the builds actually run - on the agents.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the build to use the Hosted VS2017 agent queue to be able to use C# 7 features.

[Hosted agents](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted)